# Adapting Page Post Queries from Facebook API 2.5 -> 2.7

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.5

I'm currently grabbing post-level insights from my FB page 2.5 for a dashboard to see how well recent posts are doing; a simple benchmark/performance manager dashboard that does all the querying on the front-end [js api].

The calls/procedure I used to use:

1) Get my posts

```
[page_id]/posts
```

2) Then loop them and pull the post data from two synchronous calls

```
// A) gets all the metrics
[page_post_id]/insights

// B) gets other data critical for front-end display
[page_post_id]/?fields=type,created_time,permalink_url
```

This works perfectly, and for as far as FB says, it will work until June 2018 (I think).

**My problem is that the call for step 2-A fails because I believe it requires a separate call for each metric.**

That 2-A call returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid query",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 3001,
    "error_subcode": 1504028,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "No Metric Specified",
    "error_user_msg": "No metric was specified to be fetched. Please specify one or more metrics to be fetched and try again.",
    "fbtrace_id": "XXXXXXXXX"
  }
}
```

*Am I wrong?*

***Is there something that could be done better or would I need to call each metric independently?***

I'll eventually need to get there in 2 years but better to address it early and get my teeth on that fresh, new data.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Cheers!

Comment: Field expansion should be able to help get this data using much less requests. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion

Comment: @CBroe This will help, let me give it a whirl and I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: @CBroe I've tried this and I'm getting the same result. I've looked at the API reference and adapted it to this (maybe it isn't formatted properly)
`[post_id]?fields=insights{post_consumptions_by_type}`

Comment: Since insights are requested using `/{object-id}/insights/{metric-name}`, it looks like this syntax doesn't work here. // You could still use batch requests though, so that you can at least reduce the number of HTTP requests necessary.

Comment: @CBroe I'll keep drilling away and see if there is any sort of solution I can find for getting multiple metrics off one call.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a similar setup in Python and ran into the same issue.I've discovered that the {metric} parameter can actually be an array of values.

In Facebook's Graph Explorer I managed to get multiple metrics in one call using this syntax:

```
<post_id>/insights/["post_stories","post_storytellers"]
```

You can add additional metrics to the array as needed.

As far as I can tell this feature is not (properly) documented in the Graph API documentation pages, so I'm not sure this usage is intended or not.